# Using Array.find() to try and dynamically grab a specific object value and return it based on Object name, nothing returning from function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array of object values each with it's own sub array of objects.

I'm attempting to use the Array.find() method to target each array node specifically and return a value from it's subarray based on name.

I have my function all written out but nothing is being returned and I keep getting a warning stating:

```
Expected to return a value at the end of the function(array-callback-return)
```

And I'm not entirely sure what I'm missing.

The function and data structure for reference as well as a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-austin-1eyty?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark):

```
const subjectTypes = [
  {
    name: "pokemon",
    details: [
      {
        type: "subtitle",
        value: "This is the subtitle for pokemon"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "marvel",
    details: [
      {
        type: "subtitle",
        value: "This is the subtitle for marvel"
      }
    ]
  }
];

const setCustomValue = (location) => {
  let value;

  switch (location) {
    case "/pokemon":
      return (value = subjectTypes.find(function (subject, idx) {
        if (subject.name === "pokemon") return subject.details.value;
      }));
    case "/marvel":
      return (value = subjectTypes.find(function (subject, idx) {
        if (subject.name === "marvel") return subject.details.value;
      }));
    default:
      return null;
  }
};

const customValue = setCustomValue("/pokemon");

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Dynamically Populated Content Below:</h2>
      <p>{customValue}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Also I'm aware that this may appear like over engineering and that I could easily just use a .map() or similar to print out values, but I'm using this as a simplified version of a larger problem I'm trying to solve that requires something like the .find() method to return a specific result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. [`Array#find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) expects a `true` or `false` from the callback. Or at the very least a truthy or falsy value.
2. The ESLint rule [array-callback-return](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/array-callback-return) reports a related problem. The callback only returns something from the `if`, not when the condition is not met. This is normally *valid* - no `return` makes the function implicitly return `undefined`. Since this value is falsy, `find` will ignore this item and continue with the next one. However, the ESLint rule is there to make these returns explicit and prevent mistakes, in case it is actually a bug that a branch of code does not return anything.
3. In the callback the return value is `subject.details.value` but the actual path is `subject.details[0].value` because `subject.details`is an array. Therefore the only return you have, produces `undefined`.
4. It's not possible to both locate a value with `.find()` and modify what is returned at the same time. You need to return the value *first* and then get a sub-section of it.
5. No need to declare and assign `value` when it is never used.

To address these, here is the code a bit cleaned up:

```
const setCustomValue = (location) => {
  let value;
  switch (location) {
    case "/pokemon":
      value = subjectTypes.find(function (subject, idx) {
        return subject.name === "pokemon";
      });
      return value.details[0].value;
    case "/marvel":
      value = subjectTypes.find(function (subject, idx) {
        return subject.name === "pokemon";
      });
      return value.details[0].value;
    default:
      return null;
  }
};
```

To avoid some of the repetition, you can extract the `.find()` and `return` logic outside the `switch`:

```
const setCustomValue = (location) => {
  let name;
  switch (location) {
    case "/pokemon":
      name = "pokemon";
      break;
    case "/marvel":
      name = "marvel";
      break;
    default:
      return null;
  }

  const value = subjectTypes.find((subject) => subject.name === name);
  return value.details[0].value;
};
```

The whole `switch` can be eliminated by using a simple lookup instead:

```
const paths = {
  "/pokemon": "pokemon",
  "/marvel": "marvel",
}
const setCustomValue = (location) => {
  let name = paths[location];

  if (!name) 
    return null;

  const value = subjectTypes.find((subject) => subject.name === name);
  return value.details[0].value;
};
```

And even more minimal using [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) and the [nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator)

```
const paths = {
  "/pokemon": "pokemon",
  "/marvel": "marvel",
}
const setCustomValue = (location) => 
  subjectTypes.find((subject) => subject.name === paths[location])?.details[0].value ?? null;
```

Comment: This was a huge help and also helped me better understand lookups and optional chaining! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Find returns you the element, based on a boolean query. So you have to find through name, and then get that element's value

Try:

```js
return (value = subjectTypes.find( function (subject, idx) {
  return subject.name === "pokemon";
}).details.value);
```

A cleaner way of writing this, in my totally personal opinion:

```js
value = subjectTypes.find( 
  subject => subject.name === "pokemon"
).details.value
```

Answer (score 1):

> The find() method returns the value of the first element in the
> provided array that satisfies the provided testing function. If no
> values satisfy the testing function, undefined is returned.

it will return all the element that satisfies the provided testing function

try like this :

```
return subjectTypes.find(function (subject,idx) {
        return subject.name === "pokemon"
        
}).details[0].value
```

**details** it is not an object it is an array so you have to select the oject inside the array then get the **value** of it

or you can simply  use arrow function like this

```
reuturn subjectTypes.find( (subject,idx)=> 
      subject.name === "pokemon"  
).details[0].value
```